# SQL time query from 6pm at night to 6am

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to count number of records after 6 at night and 6 in the morning?

This works until 12pm.

```
SELECT distinct count(barcode) c 
FROM table1 
where DAY(timestamp) = DAY(GETDATE())
  AND MONTH(timestamp) = MONTH(GETDATE())
  AND YEAR(timestamp) = YEAR(GETDATE())
  AND datepart(hh,timestamp) >= 18 
  AND datepart(hh,timestamp) >= 6;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: version SQL sever 2008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3656549/659190

Comment: You need to be more clear please. Are you looking for "From 6 PM today to 6 AM tomorrow", or "From 6 PM yesterday to 6 AM today", or "Before 6 AM or after 6 PM today"?

Comment: Also please don't use `timestamp` as a column name. Not only is it completely vague (timestamp of *what*?), it is also a reserved word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this may be all that you're looking for.  It removes any seconds from the GETDATE() call and adds the appropriate amount of hours to it.

```
SELECT COUNT(barcode)
FROM table1
WHERE timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR,18,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110))
  AND timestamp <= DATEADD(HOUR,6,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()+1,110))
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d2e7/9)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to count things by day, but to have the day start at 6 p.m. rather than midnight, just add an offset to the time:

```
select cast(timestamp + 0.25 as date) as theday, count(barcode)
from table1
group by cast(timestamp + 0.25 as date)
order by theday desc;
```

If you wanted to do the count for 6p.m. - 6a.m. for multiple days:

```
select cast(timestamp + 0.25 as date) as theday, count(barcode)
from table1
where datepart(hh, timestamp) in (18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
group by cast(timestamp + 0.25 as date)
order by theday desc;
```

For the most recent day, you could do:

```
select top 1 cast(timestamp + 0.25 as date) as theday, count(barcode)
from table1
where datepart(hh, timestamp) in (18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
group by cast(timestamp + 0.25 as date)
order by theday desc;
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I appreciate that.  It will take me a long time to get off the habit, though.

Comment: Cool, while you're taking suggestions. :-) https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/12/21/16567.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Sorry, you'll never get me to start lines with a semicolon or comma. I'm a human being who learned human languages.  Punctuation doesn't start a line.

Comment: That wasn't what I was suggesting at all. I was suggesting that statements should be ***terminated*** with a semi-colon. Sentences *end* with punctation, right

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

> where datefunction(timestamp)>=getdate()-1 and (datepart(hh,timestamp)>=18 or
>   datepart(hh,timestamp)<=6)

where datefunction converts datetime to date

Comment: By "where datefunction converts datetime to date" did you mean `CONVERT(DATE, [timestamp])`? Also your `OR` clause isn't correctly formed - without proper parentheses won't this include ALL rows before 6 AM for ALL dates?