# Getting time from datetime in sql server

Tags: sql

Can some body tell me what's wrong with the following code. I am trying to get the time part but it is not working.

```
declare @LssiTime nvarchar(30) 
declare @NewLssiTime varchar(5)

set @LssiTime = '2015-03-18 11:45:47.390'
SELECT  @NewLssiTime = CONVERT(varchar(5), @LssiTime,108) 
select @NewLssiTime
```

Comment: Output is    "2015-"

Comment: Just use `Select cast(@LssiTime AS Time)` OR in your  current query change as `CONVERT(varchar(8), @LssiTime,108) `

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the time of a datetime in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656492/get-the-time-of-a-datetime-in-tsql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : `SELECT  @NewLssiTime =  cast(@LssiTime as time)`

It will work for you scenerio.

Also after reading another answer, the reason why it didn't work is because sql server regards `@LssiTime` as varchar and not as `datetime`. 
In that case this will you will have to do like this:

```
Set  @NewLssiTime = CONVERT(char(5),Convert(datetime,@LssiTime) ,108)
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this does not work is because `@LssiTime` is a varchar, therefore the style `108` does nothing. Another example would be:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), 'CONVERSTION TEST', 108);

-------
CONVE
```

Just because you read `'2015-03-18 11:45:47.390'` as a date, does not change the fact that you have told SQL Server it is a `nvarchar(30)`.

The good news is that SQL Server is geared up for dealing with dates and times without `nvarchar` or `varchar`, there is a number of [date and time formats and functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186724.aspx), which mean you don't need to rely on string conversion.

Which brings me to another problem with your string format. If you ran:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2015-03-18 11:45:47.390';
SELECT CAST(@Date AS TIME(0));
```

You get the result of `11:45:47`. If you were to run this with different regional settings:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2015-03-18 11:45:47.390';
SELECT CAST(@Date AS TIME(0));
```

You get an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The **only** culture invariant format when dealing with `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME` in SQL Server is `yyyyMMdd`, so you can run the following with any settings without an error:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '20150318 11:45:47.390';
SELECT CAST(@Date AS TIME(0));
```

If You *insist* on using strings, then at the very least us an appropriate string, a valid datetime will not contain unicode characters so you may as well use `varchar`, as with the above, casting to time will implicitly convert your string to a date so you can still use:

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(30)  = '20150318 11:45:47.390'
SELECT  CAST(@Date AS TIME(0));
```

If you then want your time as a varchar(5), you must still convert to a time or datetime before converting to varchar:

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(30)  = '20150318 11:45:47.390'
DECLARE @Time VARCHAR(5) = CAST(CAST(@Date AS TIME(0)) AS VARCHAR(5));
SELECT @Time;
```